# Regex to extract size from a string

Tags: regex

Having this input string:

```
health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   test1                 5   1     222173            0     43.8gb         43.8gb
yellow open   test2                 5   1      27142           10     36.6mb         36.6mb
```

I'm using the following regex to extract some info:

```
^(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)~m
```

As you can see, from the last group (`Group 6`) I'm just the number until the first dot (`43`).

How can I correct it so the last group takes the entire number? I mean, take `43.8` and `36.6` without the `gb` and `mb`?

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/rMfWC4/3

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rMfWC4/5

Comment: Use; [`^(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/rMfWC4/6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add an alternation `(\d+\.\d+|\w+)` to match either `digit(s)` + `.` + `digit(s)` OR (`|`) `alphanum/_` chars:

```
^(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\d+\.\d+|\w+)
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2E2FVe/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+\w+\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+\W+\d+)
```

Hi, your are almost there adding the non digit capture will capture the dot(.) or whatever special characters, and adding \d will capture the digit again + sign will capture the digits if it contains more than one.
   I hope this will helps you. Good Luck.